# How to express "there exists a unique X" in Coq?

Tags: coq

I was wondering if there is a **succinct** way of writing that there exists a unique something (i.e. write unique existential quantifier) in Coq?

For example, to say that there exists an `x` s.t. `2 + x = 4`:

```
Goal exists x, 2 + x = 4.
```

How can I write that there exists a **unique** `x` with the same property?

I know I can replicate the predicate in the `s.t.` part like this:

```
Goal exists x, 2 + x = 4 /\ forall y, 2 + y = 4 -> y = x.
```

But this is a lot of repetition in general, and is there a way to somehow encode a new quantifier, and write:

```
Goal exists1, 2 + x = 4.
```

to express the same goal?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Coq already provides an `exists!` notation.  For example:

```
Goal exists! x, 2 + x = 4.
Proof.
exists 2. split.
+ reflexivity.
+ intros. injection H; intro.
  symmetry; assumption.
Qed.
```